# Добавление календаря ниже предыдущего

Tags: javascript

Правильно ли выполнена реализация добавления календаря на страницу? Как сделать что б стрелки вперед, назад работали именно в новом созданном календаре?

```js
let monthSelect = document.getElementById("rec_month");

monthSelectFill(monthSelect, [{"text"  : "Январь",  "value" : "1"},  {"text"  : "Февраль",  "value" : "2"},  {"text"  : "Март",  "value" : "3"},
  {"text"  : "Апрель",  "value" : "4"},  {"text"  : "Май",  "value" : "5"},  {"text"  : "Июнь",  "value" : "6"},
  {"text"  : "Июль",  "value" : "7"},  {"text"  : "Август",  "value" : "8"},  {"text"  : "Сентябрь",  "value" : "9"},
  {"text"  : "Октябрь",  "value" : "10"},  {"text"  : "Ноябрь",  "value" : "11"},  {"text"  : "Декабрь",  "value" : "12"},
 
]);

function monthSelectFill(select, arr) {
  arr.forEach(function(option) {
    select.add(new Option(option.text, option.value))
  });

}


let yearSelect = document.getElementById("rec_year");
let date = new Date();
let currentYear = date.getFullYear();

yearSelectFill(yearSelect, range (1980, currentYear));

function yearSelectFill(select, arr) {
  arr.forEach(function(elem) {
    select.add(new Option(elem))
  });

}
function range (from, to) {
  let result = [];

  for (let i = from; i<=to; i++){
    result.push(i);
  }
  return result;
}
function copy () { 
  let div= document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute("id", "div");
div.innerHTML = 
  
  '<table id="calendar">'+
  '<thead>'+
    '<tr>'+
      '<td id="naz_year" class="naz_year">‹‹</td>'+
      '<td id="naz_month" class="naz_month">‹</td>'+
     '<td id="itog" class="itog" colspan="3"></td>'+
      '<td id="vper_month" class="vper_month">›</td>'+
      '<td id="vper_year" class="vper_year">››</td>'+
    '<tr><td>Пн<td>Вт<td>Ср<td>Чт<td>Пт<td>Сб<td>Вс'+
      '</thead>'+
  '<tbody id = dni> </tbody>'+
'</table>' ;
calendars.prepend(div);
сalendarN();
if (document.querySelector('table') != null)  {
  revomeBtn.removeAttribute('disabled');
} 
if ((document.querySelector('table')) == null) {
  revomeBtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
}
function сalendarN () {


let year = document.getElementById("rec_year").value;
  
let mon = document.getElementById("rec_month").value;




mon = mon - 1;

function calendar(id, year, mon) {

let  Dlast = new Date(year,mon+1,0).getDate(),
    D = new Date(year,mon,Dlast),
   
    DNlast = new Date(D.getFullYear(),D.getMonth(),Dlast).getDay(),
    DNfirst = new Date(D.getFullYear(),D.getMonth(),1).getDay(),
    calendar = '<tr>',
    month=["Январь","Февраль","Март","Апрель","Май","Июнь","Июль","Август","Сентябрь","Октябрь","Ноябрь","Декабрь"];
if (DNfirst != 0) {
  for(let  i = 1; i < DNfirst; i++) calendar += '<td>';
}else{
  for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++) calendar += '<td>';
}

for(let  i = 1; i <= Dlast; i++) {
  if (i == new Date().getDate() && D.getFullYear() == new Date().getFullYear() && D.getMonth() == new Date().getMonth()) {
    calendar += '<td class="today">' + i;
  }else{
    
    calendar += '<td class="kol" id="kol">' + i;
    
  }

  if (new Date(D.getFullYear(),D.getMonth(),i).getDay() == 0) {
    calendar += '<tr>';
  } 
  
}

if (DNlast != 0) {
  for(let  i = DNlast; i < 7; i++) calendar += '<td>';
}



document.getElementById('dni').innerHTML = calendar;
document.getElementById('itog').innerHTML = month[D.getMonth()] +' '+ D.getFullYear() + ` года`;
document.getElementById('itog').dataset.month = D.getMonth();
document.getElementById('itog').dataset.year = D.getFullYear();

}


calendar("calendar", year, mon);


       
  document.getElementById('naz_month').onclick = function() {
  calendar("calendar", document.getElementById('itog').dataset.year, parseFloat(document.getElementById('itog').dataset.month) - 1);
  }
 
  document.getElementById('vper_month').onclick = function() {
    calendar("calendar", document.getElementById('itog').dataset.year, parseFloat(document.getElementById('itog').dataset.month) + 1);
  }

  document.getElementById('naz_year').onclick = function() {
    calendar("calendar", document.getElementById('itog').dataset.year, parseFloat(document.getElementById('itog').dataset.month) - 12);
    }

    document.getElementById('vper_year').onclick = function() {
      calendar("calendar", document.getElementById('itog').dataset.year, parseFloat(document.getElementById('itog').dataset.month) + 12);
    }
let col = document.querySelectorAll('#kol');
col.forEach(function(item){
  item.onclick = function () {
    item.classList.toggle('toggle');
  };
});
}
let addBtn =document.getElementById("addBtn");
addBtn.onclick = function() {
copy(); 

  
}
if ((document.getElementById("rec_month").value) == 'none' || (document.getElementById("rec_year").value) == 'none')  {
  addBtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
}

const enableaddBtn = function enableaddBtn() {
  if (((document.getElementById("rec_month").value) != 'none') && ((document.getElementById("rec_year").value) != 'none')) {
    addBtn.removeAttribute('disabled');
  } else {
    addBtn.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
  }
}
document.getElementById("rec_month").onchange = enableaddBtn;
document.getElementById("rec_year").onchange = enableaddBtn;



document.getElementById("revomeBtn").addEventListener('click', Udl)


function Udl () {
 

let listItems = document.querySelector('#calendars div');
listItems.parentNode.lastChild.remove();
if ((document.querySelector('table')) == null) {
  revomeBtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
}
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
    
<header id="men">
    <select id="rec_month">
      <option  value="none" selected>“Выбрать месяц” </option>
    </select>
    <select id="rec_year">
      <option  value="none" selected>“Выбрать год”</option>
    </select>
    <p><button id="addBtn" >Создать</button> 
    <button id="revomeBtn">Удалить</button>
  </p>
</header>


<div id="calendars"></div>
```